# MySQL - Merge first query results into a column of the second query

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables and I would like to know if there is any way to merge the results of the first query so that they appear as a column on the second query. Here is an example:

Table 1

```
FolderTable

ID  NAME    PATH
1    c: 
2    tmp     1
3     test    1,2

SELECT name FROM FolderTable WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
Result:
c:
tmp
test
```

Table 2

```
ImageTable

ID  NAME        FOLDER_ID
1    hi.jpg       3
2    blah.jpg     3
3    overwlow.jpg 3

SELECT name FROM ImageTable WHERE id = 2
Result:
NAME
blah.jpg
```

WHAT I WANT:

```
Result:
NAME        PATH
blah.jpg    c:\tmp\test
```

How do I write a querty that merges the output of the first query into a PATH column of the second query separated by "\"? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
       SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY ID SEPARATOR '\')
         FROM FolderTable 
        WHERE id BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(ID)
                            FROM FolderTable
                           WHERE ID < ImageTable.FOLDER_ID
                             AND PATH IS NULL) 
                     AND ImageTable.FOLDER_ID
 FROM ImageTable WHERE id = 2
```

Comment: Nice. If I switch out the "3" to ImageTable.folderId, I am nearly there. But how do I switch out the "1, 2" to the FolderTable.path?

Comment: I haven't seen 'FOLDER_ID'... I suppose that a folder path in FolderTable ends in `ImageTable.FOLDER_ID` ans starts with the nearest null `PATH` `ImageTable.FOLDER_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

Look into INNER JOIN

```
SELECT 
    FolderTable.Name AS FolderName, ImageTable.Name AS ImageName 
FROM 
    FolderTable 
INNER JOIN 
    ImageTable ON ImageTable.FolderId = FolderTable.ID
```

You can concatenate the fields together with "\" if you wish